# Setting up caching for APIGateway Methods

Tags: templates, caching, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have following CF Template

```
{
    "Conditions":{
        "CreatedProdStage" : {...}
    }
    ...
    "Resources":{
        "GetMethod": {
            ...
        },
        "ApiDeployement":{
            ...
        },
        "ProdStage":{
            "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
            "Condition":"CreatedProdStage",
            "Properties": {
                "DeploymentId":"...",
                "RestApiId":"...",
                "MethodSettings":[{
                    "CachingEnabled":true,
                    "HttpMethod":{"Ref":"GetMethod"},
                    "ResourcePath":"/"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I am getting error

> Invalid method setting path:
>   /~1/st-GetMetho-xxxAUMMRWxxx/caching/enabled. Must be one of:
>   [/deploymentId, /description,
>   /cacheClusterEnabled/cacheClusterSize/clientCertificateId/{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/metrics/enabled,
>   /{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/logging/dataTrace,
>   /{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/logging/loglevel,
>   /{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/throttling/burstLimit/{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/throttling/rateLimit/{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/caching/ttlInSeconds,
>   /{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/caching/enabled,
>   /{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/caching/dataEncrypted,
>   /{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/caching/requireAuthorizationForCacheControl,
>   /{resourcePath}/{httpMethod}/caching/unauthorizedCacheControlHeaderStrategy,
>   /*/*/metrics/enabled, /*/*/logging/dataTrace, /*/*/logging/loglevel,
>   /*/*/throttling/burstLimit /*/*/throttling/rateLimit
>   /*/*/caching/ttlInSeconds, /*/*/caching/enabled,
>   /*/*/caching/dataEncrypted,
>   /*/*/caching/requireAuthorizationForCacheControl,
>   /*/*/caching/unauthorizedCacheControlHeaderStrategy, /va

Am I missing something? I thought `ResourcePath` and `HttpMethod` are the only required attributes

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still arriving at this, but is NOT using cache, I have provided an example for setting throttling and logging on the whole API. I could not figure it out until I started playing around with the ResourcePath and HttpMethod, and noticed the error changing.

Please note that I used `*` for both path and method and `USED QUOTATIONS`. It will fail without quotations.

```
  ProdStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      RestApiId: !Ref StunningDisco
      DeploymentId: !Ref StunningDiscoDeployment
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: '/*'
          HttpMethod: '*'
          LoggingLevel: INFO
          DataTraceEnabled: True
          ThrottlingBurstLimit: '10'
          ThrottlingRateLimit: '10.0'

  StunningDiscoDomainMapping:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping'
    DependsOn: ProdStage
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref StunningDiscoDomain
      RestApiId: !Ref StunningDisco
      Stage: !Ref ProdStage

  StunningDiscoDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn: [StunningDiscoRootEndpoint, LightsInvokeEndpoint]
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref StunningDisco
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to enable caching on the stage with the `CacheClusterEnabled` property. This will allow you to set up caching for methods as you have done in you MethodSettings:

```
...
"ProdStage":{
        "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
        "Condition":"CreatedProdStage",
        "Properties": {
            "DeploymentId":"...",
            "RestApiId":"...",
            "CacheClusterEnabled": true
            "MethodSettings":[{
                "CachingEnabled":true,
                "HttpMethod":{"Ref":"GetMethod"},
                "ResourcePath":"/"
            }]
        }
    }
```

Then you will need to fix the given error. Your `ResourcePath` to match one of those listed in the error output. Those are not listed in the documentation, so it's a bit confusing what you need to use. What you currently have is set up for the root path only. If you want all paths use `"/*"`

APIGateWay::MethodSettings (see ResourcePath) doc: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-stage-methodsetting.html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the HttpMethod to a string instead of a reference:

```
"MethodSettings":[{
        "CachingEnabled":true,
        "HttpMethod": "GET",
        "ResourcePath":"/"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Interesting - can you post the error, if it it's different?

Comment: There is no error. The stacks got created with `HttpMethod` and `ResourcePath` changed (as you suggested) but the caching hasn't been enabled.

Comment: "true" might need to be a string as well: can you try surrounding it with quotes?